# How to show a custom <option> text in a queryset field from forms in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two model like:

```
def Product(models.Model):
    thename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

def Req(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    # other fields
```

So I have a form for Req class. I need that in the template show the 3 values of producto to select one of the queryset.

Example, that in the html have:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Brand Soap - Pieces - 1.99</option>
  <option value="2">Cokies - Box - 5.99</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show us the form too please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__unicode__` attribute

```
def Product(models.Model):
    thename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s - %s"%(self.thename, self.unity, self.price)
```

Now, render the form the way you would normally